# JSONArray Exception : Index 50 out of range [0..50). Is there any limit on JsonArray

Tags: java, android, json

I'm using `JSON` in my android application in the following manner:

- Send request to a URL & receive JSON response.
- Parse JSON response & fetch the required element "results" which is a
  JSON array.
- Loop on every i'th  element of this JSON array and continue with the
  required operation

Code:

```
Integer numberOfItemsInResp = pagination.getInt("items");
    JSONArray results = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("results");
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItemsInResp; i++){
        JSONObject perResult = results.getJSONObject(i);
    }
```

Problem is when the **i** reaches 50, then `JSONObject perResult = results.getJSONObject(i)` throws **"org.json.JSONException: Index 50 out of range [0..50)"** Exception.

Is there any limitation attached to JSONArray?

Comment: Are you sure the "results" json array has more than 50 objects?

Comment: More likely, numberOfItemsInResp is simply wrong . Why not use results.length()?

Comment: Index 50 on an array of 50 elements is n + 1, the last is 49, right?

Comment: "result" sometimes has more that 75...50 is very normal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is `numberOfItemsInResp`? Suggest you do this:

```
JSONArray results = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("results");
final int numberOfItemsInResp = results.length();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItemsInResp; i++){
    JSONObject perResult = results.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

Comment: numberOfItemsInResp is
: `Integer numberOfItemsInResp = pagination.getInt("items");` which I'm using to check just how many items will be there in the response

Comment: @Sameera the `results` array had fewer elements than the value in their `items` int. By using `.length()` we ensure it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a simple debug, see how your array looks like, most likely you don't have enough items in the array as the index you provide, the answers above are pretty clear in this regard.