# I am getting Error like below in android using volley.error is , org.json.JSONException: Index 3 out of range [0..3)

Tags: android

I am using volley library to achive network operation when i try to ru the program using below program i am gettin warning and getting size less than what i have in the url the warning message is org.json.JSONException: Index 3 out of range [0..3).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView results;   
String JsonURL = "http://184.73.181.186/jsondata.php";
String data = "";   
RequestQueue requestQueue;
MyCustomBaseAdapter myCustomBaseAdapter;
ArrayList<StudentInfo> studentInfoList = new ArrayList<StudentInfo>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);       
    results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jsonData);      
    JsonArrayRequest arrayreq = new JsonArrayRequest(JsonURL,                               
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {                      
                    try {                      
                  for(int i=0;i<lenghthofarray;i++){
                            JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            final int numberOfItemsInResp = jresponse.length();
                            StudentInfo studentInfo = new StudentInfo();
                            String fname = jresponse.getString("fName");
                            String lName = jresponse.getString("lName");
                            String rollNo = jresponse.getString("rollNo");
                            String profilePic =  jresponse.getString("profilePic");
                            studentInfo.setFname(fname);
                            studentInfo.setLname(lName);
                            studentInfo.setRoolNo(rollNo);
                            studentInfo.setStudpic(profilePic);
                            studentInfoList.add(studentInfo);

                            list.add(profilePic);
                            myCustomBaseAdapter = new MyCustomBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(),studentInfoList);





                            JSONObject colorObj = response.getJSONObject(0);

                        JSONArray colorArry = colorObj.getJSONArray("marks");                        

                        for (int ii = 0; ii < colorArry.length(); ii++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = colorArry.getJSONObject(i);


                            String subjectName, marks;
                            subjectName = jsonObject.getString("subjectName");
                            marks = jsonObject.getString("marks");

                        }
                            data += "\nfName " + fname +
                                    "\nHex Value : " + lName + "\n\n\n"+rollNo+"\n"+profilePic+"\n";
                        }
                        results.setText(data);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        }
    },


            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                // Handles errors that occur due to Volley
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                }
            }
    );

}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSONArray Exception : Index 50 out of range \[0..50). Is there any limit on JsonArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827475/jsonarray-exception-index-50-out-of-range-0-50-is-there-any-limit-on-jsona)

Comment: Use `response.length()` instead of `lengthofarray` in your `for` loop.

Comment: The Size of array is 100 i am getting only 4 elements

Comment: even using response.length i am getting same warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in(i),replace i with ii

JSONObject jsonObject = colorArry.getJSONObject(i);

solved one
JSONObject jsonObject = colorArry.getJSONObject(ii);